# ios load images on scroll from web server

Tags: ios5

For the iPhone 5.0 I am getting lot of image(image url's) and text data from server in a json form. My requirement is to load the first five images from the server and when the user scrolls down the next five images load and so on. I need to show it in a UITableViewCell. By doing this I can reduce the network calls and make the application faster on the device.

Currently, I am using a background thread to load images, but they continuously load in the background. I don't want to do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code from Apple.
It should answer your question.

[LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html)

it uses `UIScrollViewDelegate` to implement the following function

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate)
    {
        [self loadImagesForOnscreenRows];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self loadImagesForOnscreenRows];
}
```

Basically it does what you want - just load image of the visible cell.

With `[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]` you can call the `startIconDownload` function to the specified tableCell

Comment: I saw this post before ask ..but i am unable to understand the whole concept  ....:)

Comment: Mineschan actually i want to implement this on UITabelView Cell. cane you please tell me ,or can i not implement on UITable view or it is essay to implement using scroll view

Comment: `UITableView` is inherits from `UIScrollView`, that means you can implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` within the `UITableView` subclass, so that would be absolutely possible.

Comment: Can you also please tell me one thing more ,how can i load first five images from server by default ,and when user scroll then next five load from server . i am unable to understand because i am totally new on iOs development

Comment: You gotta learn some basic stuff and read the apple API document before doing some complicated stuff.Grab some books,srsly.